# Plotting in loop, keeping old ones & also pausing in between

Tags: python, plot

(1) I want to plot in a loop while keeping old plots and 
(2) I want to pause after each plotting so that I can analyse the plot.

While I can do either (1) or (2) but not both. How can I do both?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(w,x,b):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-(w*x+b)))

w1 = np.array([0.5,3,5.5])
b1 = np.array([0.5,3,5.5])
X = np.linspace(-20,20,100)

for w in w1:
    for b in b1:
        Y = sigmoid(X,w,b)
        plt.plot(X,Y, label = f'w = {w} \n b = {b}' )
        plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1.05,1))
        plt.pause(1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a bit tricky to accomplish, as it tends to depend on the environment where you are running matplotlib. Are you using the regular Python interpreter, IPython or Jupyter? Or an IDE such as Spyder?

Comment: I am using Google colab notebook.

Comment: Ok. Do you want each plot in a separate figure, or everything in one plot?

Comment: I want all plots in one figure.

Comment: Sorry, I could not make this work in colab. It seems to work a bit differently than other interactive environments. You might ask colab support whether it's possible.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But can you share your code. Maybe I can learn from it.